# CRMService and ICRMService

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-4

In CRM 4.0.
In the plugin i extracted ICrmService from the context and created a function that the ICrmService is passed as a parameter.
I also created a console application that creates a CRMService, i want to pass the CRMService to the above function but the function expect ICrmService not CRMService.

what do i do in this situation?

(the function is inside a dll that both the Plugin and the console application can use).

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple. You have to create a wrapper for the `CrmService` class, which implements [`ICrmService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc156387.aspx).

```
public class CrmServiceWrapper : ICrmService
{
    private bool _disposed;
    private readonly CrmService _service;

    public CrmServiceWrapper(CrmService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public Guid Create(BusinessEntity entity)
    {
        return _service.Create(entity);            
    }

    ...
}
```

Now you could wrap an instance of CrmService with this class and pass it to your method.